# Can't edit element on google page, no CSS selector works

Tags: css, userstyles

I'm trying to make a Google userstyle based on Discord's color scheme. Even though I have no programming experience whatsoever, it has been pretty straightforward (Inspect element > Copy-paste to Stylus) but now there's an element that I can't edit. It's the "next" arrow in the video cards that appear in the results for a search. Here it is: [The button on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CpCa.png)

When inspecting it, the selector just shows up as "element", that didn't work, right-clicking and copying the selector (I'm using FIrefox) also didn't work, and using live CSS editors didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because they use a fake html element called `g-right-button`. Just change it to `div` and you'll be fine.

(You can also just make a `g-right-button { .. }` selector)

[image: Why]

You can also see and change properties from inspector.

[image: Also]

Comment: I think he just couldn't select it with CSS because it wasn't a "valid" tag...

Comment: Thanks! This is way out of my league, is there a way to find this out or is it just reading the code and trial and error? Also, how would the code look like then? Using just `g-right-button { .. }` didn't work for me. It changes the color behind the button, not on the button itself.

Comment: Try using `g-fab { background: black !important }`. Trial and error... also, when you select an element in debugger it shows you below what properties it has (eg. `g-fab { background: white }`). You can get from that which selector to use, you can even change it... I changed the answer above ^